# Is there a way to subscribe to a room's `participantConnected` event without becoming a participant?

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

One can use the `room` returned from calling `Video.connect` to subscribe to a room's `participantConnected` event, so that all kinds of different logic can be executed when a new participant joins a room.   I can also query rooms remotely without `Video.connect` to see how many participants are currently connected.  However, I would like be able to use the `participantConnected` event to display in real time if someone is in a room, without actually joining the room.

**Is this possible and how would I do that without becoming a participant via `Video.connect` and without polling twilio's api?**

Preferably, I'd like to do this on the javascript side, but I could use twilio's api wrapper library on the server-side if I had to.   I just want the client to get notified somehow when someone enters or leaves a room so I can display whether the room is empty in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive those events with the client SDK, you would need to join the room as you would need a connection to it in order to receive events from it.

You can, however, [subscribe to status callback webhooks for rooms](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks#rooms-callbacks). There are lots of events that a room emits that can be received as webhooks, such as `room-created`, `room-ended`, and, as you've asked for, `participant-connected`.

You can set the `statusCallback` when you [create a room with the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/rooms-resource#post-list-resource) and you can see [all the parameters that are sent as part of the webhook request here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/video/api/status-callbacks#rooms-event-parameters).